# What's the right place for business logic?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

You're working on your own version of stackoverflow :-)

You're using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework (model-first approach if it matters). So, you have a couple of classes generated by EF:

```
class Question {...}
class Answer {...}
```

You also has all the related stuff (`ObjectContext`, etc). You have all the related code to handle a scenario of answering the question (`StackoverflowController` with `AnswerQuestion`[get] + `AnswerQuestion`[post] actions, also a view to display a fancy form - `Stackoverflow/Answer`).

Your customer is a very tough guy, so he defines a set of business rules:

1. Nobody should be able to answer the question in first 5 minutes after the question is asked (they should get a message).
2. When the answer is posted, topic starter should receive a notification.
3. The main page should display 20 latest questions.
4. When displaying answers for every question, they should be ordered by votes.
5. When questions are downvoted with total of -10, they should be closed.
6. When answers are downvoted with total of -10, their posters should get anti-bonus of -20 to their reputation.

etc.

The question is - given the facts described above, where would you implement your customer's business rules?

I don't really like the idea of having the code like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_container.Questions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Posted).Take(20).ToList());
    }
}
```

But how would you name the right place for this logic? And what interface should it have? Is it something like this:

```
// implements the business logic, interacts with repositories
public static class Stackoverflow
{
    public static IEnumerable<Question> GetRecentQuestions() { ... } // logic here!
    public static void PostAnswer(Question question, Answer answer) { ... } // logic here!
}
```

?

Comment: This sort of discursive, open-ended question truly belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: flagged for moving to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: typical game developer response: "You should use a StackoverflowManager class, and it should be static. Also, make sure the static instance has an extremely complex state at all times." ^.^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use a service layer to handle this for you:

```
public Interface IStackoverflowService
{
    IEnumerable<Question> GetRecentQuestions();
    void PostAnswer(Question question, Answer answer);
}

public class StackoverflowService : IStackoverflowService
{
    private StackoverflowDbContext _container;

    public StackoverflowService(StackoverflowDbContext container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Question> GetRecentQuestions() 
    { 
         var model = _container.Questions.OrderByDescending(x => x.Posted);
         return model.Take(20);
    } 

    public void PostAnswer(Question question, Answer answer) { ... }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IStackoverflowService _stackoverflowService;

    public HomeController(IStackoverflowService stackoverflowService)
    {
        _stackoverflowService = stackoverflowService;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _stackoverflowService.GetRecentQuestions();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

You can even break it out into multiple services such as a `QuestionsService`, an `AnswersService`, a `UsersService`, etc.

Comment: Good answer, suggest putting an interface on the StackOverflowService so it can be mocked for unit testing.

Comment: @jeremyalan added interface for an example.

Comment: Should this service provide an access to the repositories for cases like "get question by id"? Or should I have `GetQuestionById()` as a member of `IStackoverflowService`?

Comment: @loki2302 if you are using the repository pattern then yes, that is actually how my service layer works. You can abstract it as much as possible from the service layer, such as making it call a business layer which access the data layer, and binding down to DTO's and ViewModels along the way if you desire.